# What is the IUPAC name of [Cr(H2O)5Cl]Cl2.H2O

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, nomenclature, coordination-compounds

What is the IUPAC name of $\ce{[Cr(H2O)5Cl]Cl2.H2O}$?
The net says that the correct name is Pentaaquachloridochromium(III) chloride.

But do we not have to account for the water molecule present outside the coordination sphere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should account for the water molecule outside the coordination sphere. In most cases, you do not need to do so, but if you are looking for specificity and/or want to describe the physical or chemical properties of this particular hydrate, it is advised to also mention the number of molecules of water of crystalliation.

The correct IUPAC name, in that case, would be Pentaaquachloridochromium(III) chloride monohydrate.

For additional hydrate naming rules and prefixes, check out [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IUPAC_nomenclature_of_inorganic_chemistry#Naming_hydrates)

Answer (score 0):

The formula [Cr(H$_2$O)$_5$Cl]Cl2.H$_2$O describes the crystal. It contains the cation [Cr(H$_2$O)$_5$Cl]$^{2+}$, twice the anion Cl$^-$ and one water molecule in it's lattice.

The IUPAC name you gave Pentaaquachloridochromium(III) chloride only describes the cation, so it does not take the anion and the water molecule.